# Fatal Error when I try to launch my custom MapActivity

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, geopoints

This in a bit complex issue so read carefully.

I have tried to realize a map that

-shows my current position,

-when I click on a point in the map, the app should place a custom geoPoint getting latitude and longitude to pass these to an activity to create a new Pub object

-the map on start must show the positions of Pubs saved before

Following [this tutorial](http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial/details/53/Integrating+Google+Maps+in+Android+App/) I have created these class

**Class MyMap**:

```
public class MyMap extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
    private MapView mapView;
     private LocationManager locManager;
     private MapLocationOverlay itemizedOverlay;
     GeoPoint point ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
        setContentView(R.layout.mymap);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        // invalidate the map in order to show changes
        mapView.invalidate();

        MapController controller = mapView.getController();


        // Use the location manager through GPS
        locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, this);

        //get the current location (last known location) from the location manager
        Location location = locManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



            //if location found display as a toast the current latitude and longitude
        if (location != null) {
            point = new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(location.getLongitude() *1E6));
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Current location:\nLatitude: " + location.getLatitude()
                            + "\n" + "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            controller.animateTo(point);
            controller.setZoom(13);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot fetch current location!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        // fetch the drawable - the pin that will be displayed on the map
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_custom);

        // create and add an OverlayItem to the MyItemizedOverlay list
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
        itemizedOverlay = new MapLocationOverlay(drawable,this);
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

        // add the overlays to the map
        mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
        mapView.invalidate();

        GestureDetector gd=new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector ());
        itemizedOverlay.setGestureDetector(gd);

        //when the current location is found – stop listening for updates (preserves battery)
        locManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }





    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;

    }

    /* When the activity starts up, request updates */

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, this);
    }


    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locManager.removeUpdates(this); //activity pauses => stop listening for updates
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }



    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }


    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }


    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    public class MyGestureDetector  extends SimpleOnGestureListener {


        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {

            // fetch the correspondent point from the map
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());

            // create an overlay item and clear all others
            OverlayItem o = new OverlayItem(p, null, null);
            itemizedOverlay.clear();
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(o);

            // add the overlay item
            mapView.getOverlays().clear();
            mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
            mapView.invalidate();

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),
                    Locale.getDefault());

            // get the address based on the coordinates
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                String addressString = "";
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0)
                            .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                        addressString += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i)
                                + " - ";
                }

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), addressString,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return true;
        }

        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

And class **MapLocationOverlay**:

```
public class MapLocationOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

       private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
       private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

       private List<Pub> pubList;
       private Context context;



       public MapLocationOverlay(Context context, List<Pub> pubList, Drawable marker) {
          super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
          try{
              this.context = context;
              this.pubList = pubList;
              if (pubList == null) {
                  pubList = new ArrayList<Pub>();
              }
              populate();
          }
          catch(RuntimeException e){

          }

       }

       public MapLocationOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context ctx) {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

        }

       @Override
       protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
           try{
           Pub c=pubList.get(i);
              GeoPoint point =
                       new GeoPoint((int) (c.getLatitude() * 1e6), (int) (c.getLongitude() * 1e6));
              return new OverlayItem(point, c.getName(), null);
          }
          catch(RuntimeException e){

          }
          return mOverlays.get(i);
       }

       public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
            mOverlays.add(overlay);
            populate();
        }

       public void clear() {

            mOverlays.clear();
            populate();
        }

       @Override
       public boolean onTap(final int index) {
           Pub c=pubList.get(index);
           final String name=c.getName();
           final String description=c.getDescription();
           final String street=c.getStreet();
         // BrewLocation brewLocation = brewLocations.get(index);
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
          builder.setTitle("Visualizzare la nota "+name+"?")
                   .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                         Intent pubDetails = new Intent(context, InfoPub.class);
                         pubDetails.putExtra("name", name);
                         pubDetails.putExtra("description", description);
                         pubDetails.putExtra("street", street);
                         context.startActivity(pubDetails);
                      }
                   }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                         dialog.cancel();
                      }
                   });
          AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show();

          return true; // we'll handle the event here (true) not pass to another overlay (false)
       }


        /**
         * Override this method to handle a "tap" on a balloon. By default, does nothing 
         * and returns false.
         * 
         * @param index - The index of the item whose balloon is tapped.
         * @return true if you handled the tap, otherwise false.
         */
        protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index) {
            return false;
        }

          @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {

                // when the user lifts its finger
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
                }

            public GestureDetector getGestureDetector() {
                    return gestureDetector;
                }

            public void setGestureDetector(GestureDetector gestureDetector) {
                this.gestureDetector = gestureDetector;
            }

       @Override
       public int size() {
           //return pubList.size();
           return mOverlays.size();
       }



    }
```

Is not totally complete but should run, according the tutorial followed, unfortunately when I try to launch the activity the app crash with a fatal error.

This is the error stack:

```
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.myapp.mymapapp/it.myapp.mymapapp.MyMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.populate(ItemizedOverlay.java:312)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at it.myapp.mymapapp.utility.MapLocationOverlay.addOverlay(MapLocationOverlay.java:72)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at it.myapp.mymapapp.MyMap.onCreate(MyMap.java:89)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
10-13 17:25:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(28215):    ... 11 more
```

How Could I fix this?
What's missing?

Comment: Have you added appropriate permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: You have a null pointer at line 312 - at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.populate(ItemizedOverlay.java:312) what is that line?

Comment: @ShashankKadne yes there all permissions,

Comment: @Simon

ItemizedOverlay is a class of the library not a my class, on the line 312 happen an error propagation of something that gone wrong in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing `point` in `onCreate()`, except if you get a valid `lastKnownLocation()`.

This non initialized `point` is added to an OverlayItem, that is added to the ItemizedOverlay.

When Mapview try to get the Geopoint to draw Marker, it gets a `null` and bummmm!!

Just replace:

```
GeoPoint point;
```

by:

```
GeoPoint point = new Geopoint(0,0);
```

and it will not crash anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! this was the cause of the crash... however the map doesn't work, freeze on the start location and I cannot do nothing: doesn't scroll and doesn't happen anything when I try to click on a place. What is the reason?

Comment: The problem is with your `MyGestureDetector` class. You are using `return true` in more then one place that you shouldn't. You should return true only when you used the motion event to do something, otherwise you should `return false` to informe that the motion event can be used by other classes (i.e. the Mapview to move the map).

Answer (score 0):

Your `createItem()` implementation is rather strange:

1. You catch a `RuntimeException` and do nothing with it. If nothing else, you should be logging the exception, particularly so long as you are having problems with your code.
2. Your `size()` method is based off of `mOverlays`, yet you do not use `mOverlays` in `createItem()` (unless the mishandled `RuntimeException` occurs). Either use `mOverlays` consistently or get rid of it entirely.

Beyond that, something that `ItemizedOverlay` expects to not be `null` is indeed `null`. One possibility is the "snippet" (third parameter to the `OverlayItem` constructor), which you are setting to `null`. Another possibility is that `c.getName()` is returning `null`, and perhaps `ItemizedOverlay` needs the name to be non-`null`.

If nothing else, go back to the original code from that blog post, get that working, and then *slowly* modify it to have your desired functionality, testing as you go.

Comment: I have used successful many times a map overlay to show my position and the geopoints on the locations passed through a list but I have problem to implement also a function to place a new geopoint on clicked location so I have merged my solution with the code to get the coordinates on click but unfortunately nothing seems work so I have placed some try catch to see if the class run ignoring the critical code blocks... but nothing, cannot figure how I could obtain a working implementation to solve my problem. (Sorry for my bad English)